# Meaning of "signo solito"

Tags: vocabulary

What is the meaning of *signo solito*? [For example](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=0Sz2VYI0l1IC&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=dicio%20paterna&source=bl&ots=4zOp4waZrM&sig=es7u-q8ivNgakbMJPX6MzsEWq9Y&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizu-v9grHWAhXmCpoKHdxtDr4Q6AEIDDAB#v=onepage&q=dicio%20paterna&f=true):

> The arrangements were explained to Jem by interpreters "skilled in Latin and in Turkish," and being satisfied, he confirmed the Hospitallers' plans *signo turchico solito*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "with the usual sign (or signal)." Presumably he means he's [shaking his head](https://www.dailysabah.com/life/2016/01/30/nodding-winking-hand-gestures-visitors-experiences-with-turkish-gestures), whereas everywhere else we nod for assent.

For the phrase used in actual Latin, see Ammianus Marcellinus 25.6: "Adesse hostes signo solito demonstrabam" (I was pointing out that enemies were present with the usual signal.)